# Casting Instruction to Value LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm trying to cast an instruction to a value as follows:

```
Value *def_val = (dyn_cast<Value>(instr));
```

however, this produces the following error:

```
error: non-pointer
  operand type 'llvm::Value' incompatible with nullptr
return isa<X>(Val) ? cast<X>(Val) : nullptr;
```

I also tried casting to a `Value*` and also placing the `*` in front of the whole `dyn_cast` expression, however none of these options work.

Comment: What is `instr` and where is it declared?

Comment: You are casting it to a Value but defining it as a Value pointer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your dynamic_cast has to be to value* (and the argument to the dynamic_cast will need to be a pointer to something that already handles polymorphic behavior. If that latter is not the case you may be able to use some other cast but dynamic_cast will not work.

Comment: This is not `dynamic_cast`. It's [llvm's hand-rolled RTTI](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates).

Answer (score 1):

Get the pointer of Instruction:

```
Value *val = dyn_cast<Value>(&instr);
```